# Script to execute on CVS check-in, without access to the server?

Tags: continuous-integration, cvs, scripting, post-commit

Is it possible to write a script that executes certain instructions, and is triggered by any check-in to a CVS repository?

The script would scan the list of files in the change-set and do a copy operation on certain files in a certain sub-directory.

I would hopefully be able to execute various console applications, including ones written in .NET.

Problem is, I need this done quickly and I don't have access to the CVS server, due to corporate IT red-tape, etc.

Is there a way to set this up on one of the client workstations instead?

Can it be done without interfering with my working folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a .NET library that seems up to the task - SharpCVSLib.

http://csharpopensource.com/sharpcvslib.aspx

(Hopefully it will work on a developer workstation and not need to be hosted on the CVS server.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you get [commit notifications by email](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/001058.html) as this blog shows?  If so, you could be able to use [maildrop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildrop) (or good old `procmail`, etc) to run arbitrary commands and scripts on your workstation when the commit notification mails arrive.